# how to convert an arrary of 16-bit unsigned intergers into ascii string in matlab

Tags: matlab, ascii

I am looking for a way to convert an array of 16-bit unsigned integer into ASCII char array. I am using char to do the conversion

```
D=[65 65 65 65];
char(D)
```

which will show 4 'A'. However, since each number in D is 16-bit, I expect it to convert each number to 2 chars. For example, if I have

```
D=[16707]
char(D)
```

I expect it gives me two chars 'A' and 'C'. But char always return 1 character. Is that anyway to force char to convert like the way I stated? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this, you need to write your own function.

You can use char() to convert most significant byte and least significant byte separately.

```
k      = 16707;
first  = char(bitand(bitshift(k, -8), 255));
second = char(bitand(k, 255));
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at 
http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/char.html

It cleatly states that the char function is valid only for 8 bit numbers. you can convert each part of cell of the array with this and contact the results for each two cells.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`typecast`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/typecast.html) to convert each `uint16` to two `uint8`, and then apply `char`. Make sure that the input to `typecastr` is really of type `uint16`.

If you need to reverse char order, use [`swapbytes`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/swapbytes.html) on the `uint16` vector.

```
>> D = [16707 16708];

>> char(typecast(uint16(D),'uint8'))
ans =
CADA

>> char(typecast(swapbytes(uint16(D)),'uint8'))
ans =
ACAD
```